# How to check mysql status on Unix

Tags: mysql, ssh

I check mysql server status by ssh to the server.

```
$ mysql
mysql> status
```

Beside this way, is there any other way that I can use ssh to remote check the status? Since there are many mysql servers, I don't want to ssh to each of them. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [mysqladmin](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqladmin.html), which can query the database for it's status.

On the localhost, you can store the password in a [~/.my.cnf file](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/option-files.html) (make sure the permissions are strict). Here's an example from the MySQL 5.1 manual:

```
[client]
# The following password will be sent to all standard MySQL clients
password="my_password"
```

Then, you can automatically query the remote MySQL server like this:

```
mysqladmin --host=db1.example.org --user=admin status
Uptime: 884637  Threads: 1  Questions: 5534424  Slow queries: 144  Opens: 4444  Flush tables: 21  Open tables: 166  Queries per second avg: 6.259
```

You'll want to make sure that the firewall on the remote server allows these connections. You'll also want to check that the MySQL privileges allow this sort of access from a remote host. If you are concerned about packet sniffing on your LAN, then configure [MySQL to use SSL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/secure-using-ssl.html).

You can avoid these hassles by running the command through ssh.

```
ssh db1.example.org "mysqladmin status"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can combine it into one command:

```
ssh server 'echo status|mysql'
```

Beyond that, I would look at tools like [puppet](http://www.puppetlabs.com/) if you want further automation.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. I got 'bash: mysql: command not found' error.

Comment: @Stan, that means `mysql` isn't in the PATH.  You can adjust that, or get the full mysql path from `which` then put it in the command: `ssh server 'echo status|/full/path/to/mysql'`